# xcode 6 beta can't open after update Yosemite preview 6

Tags: xcode, osx-yosemite

I used Yosemite 10.10 preview5 and xcode6. it work well.

I update my macbook pro to Yosemite preview6 last night. Now I could not open any xcode project in xcode6.

I loading too long and not responding. Does any know how to solve this problem?

Comment: off topic to Apple Developer Portal, Apple Bug Reporter, Super User or Ask Different.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I can still open projects in Xcode 6 (beta 4) but when I try to build it, it gets stuck at compiling image catalog. I tried Xcode 6 beta 6. It builds fine. However, beta 6 seems to be very buggy and I don't know if I want to spend hours trying to fix errors which may not be errors in the final version of Xcode 6.

Comment: @AhRyunMoon I have downloaded the old version of Xcode commandline tool then install it. The problem was fixed. I think the main problem is new Xcode commandline tool which included in Xcode (beta 4) has some issues.

Answer (score 2):

Here what solved my problem:

- Open App Store application.
- In the menu select "Store" > "Check for Unfinished Downloads ..."
- Install the update

Regards